# Program wont loop, Prime Number finder, C

Tags: c

I just started learning C and i would like to make a program that finds how many prime numbers are within 200 and 300, but i dont seem to get it right as my program seems not to even loop. Could you suggest a fix? For those who dont know, prime numbers are those greater than 1 that cannot be formed by multiplying two smaller natural numbers. (ex. 3, 5, 7)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define START 200
#define END 300

int main()
{
    int primenum = 0, i = 0, j = 0, c = 0;
    for (i = START; i <= END; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i%j == 0)
            {
                c++;
            }
            if (c == 2)
            {
                primenum = primenum + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("tHE PRIME NUMBERS ARE %d", primenum);
}
```

Comment: because `START > END`

Comment: In the future when you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please make sure it actually *builds* (or otherwise have the behavior you ask about). The code you show will not build. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: nah still wont work right

Comment: Your program (with the `firstnum` commented out) runs (but produces wrong result) on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/mRnYtB)

Comment: You keep changing the program! Please don't do that! Thanks

Comment: i know it runs,but as u said,it produces wrong results

Comment: I think it's time for you to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially, doing some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would be very helpful. You're kind of doing the right things, but not everything is in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define START 200
#define END 300

int main()
{
    int primenum = 0, i = 0, j = 0, c = 0;
    for (i = START; i <= END; i++)
    {
        c = 2;
        for (j = 2; j <= i-1; j++)
        {
            if (i%j == 0)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        if (c == 2) primenum = primenum + 1;
    }
    printf("THE PRIME NUMBERS ARE %d", primenum);
    return 0;
}
```

I put c = 2 in the for with i because a prime number has 2 divisor (1 and itself). The for with j starts from 2 because 1 is a divisor and ends at i-1 because i is the number and each number is a divisor for itself. I tested the c value at the end of the for with j because if this value is tested inside the result is wrong. I obtained 16 prime numbers between 200 and 300.

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix some issues.

> for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) Every `number` is divisible by `1` and
>   `itself` so you need to fix this issue. You should start `j=2` to
>   `j=i-1` You need to change  `for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)` to `for (j = 2;
>   j <i; j++)`
>
> You need to reset the counter variable `c` for every number before you
>   enter the nested `for` loop.
>
> You're checking the value of `c` in the loop and that's why you're
>   getting the wrong result. You should check the value of `c` after
>   breaking out from the `loop`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define START 100
#define END 200

int main()
{
    int primenum = 0, i = 0, j = 0, c = 0;
    for (i = START; i <= END; i++)
    {
        c=2;
        for (j = 2; j <i; j++)
        {
            if (i%j == 0)
            {
                c++;
                break;
            }

        }

          if (c == 2)
            {
                primenum = primenum + 1;
            }

    }
    printf("tHE PRIME NUMBERS ARE %d", primenum);
}
```